# NSURLSession Authentication doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, basic-authentication, nsurlsession

I want to download data from a website with an authentication.
I found a good code but it doesn't worked. The code just print "nil"

```
func getData()
{
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let userPasswordString = "user:password"
let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
var running = false
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.exampleschool.de/board")
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
    (let data, let response, let error) in
    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println(dataString)
    }
    running = false
}

running = true
task.resume()
while running {
println("waiting...")
sleep(1)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Authorization header is reserved for Apple use.  You cannot modify it safely, because the Apple APIs will stomp on whatever value you put there.

You can learn about how to do authentication by reading the authentication chapter of [URL Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009507-SW1).  Note that the examples are for NSURLConnection, but the rest of the text applies to both.